# index every field in mongodb by default or auto without having me to check or set each index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, database

in our project we are creating rest api in node.js, we want index every field in database even if it is not much used in querying

how to achieve this without having to create indexes of each and when new field is added

and let me is this correct way to index every field ?

of which may create problems? like for scaling etc

I came to this decision because I have used Microsoft DocumentDB, which indexes every field by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible.

It also isn't a good idea for many reasons. Every index you have needs to be maintained, so every insert you do into the DB has to be written to the record and every single index. So having a lot of indexes makes writes slower. Also, it uses more memory. You should only index the fields that you search and sort by. If you want the entire DB to be in memory maybe consider Redis.

Comment: thank you, but I have a question how MS DocumentDB is provided by indexing all fields by default ??

Comment: I don't know but I do know that they designed the database round it. That's how they built it. MongoDB isn't designed to be used like that.